# Request all permissions simultaneously in android 6

Tags: android, permissions

On installing some third-party apk in android 6.0.1 (API 23) I see [the screen with list of multiple permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9G7y.png) to grant. Howewer, starting with API 23 android requires permissions to be requested one by one at runtime. So how this possible and how I can this in my app for android 6+ ? The phone is not rooted.

Comment: This screen just tells you that , the app will get those permissions. It will not grant permissions when you click install. It is just an information about the access details

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately its not possible from if your `targetSdkVersion >= 23` and you are running your app on Android 6.0. Best you can do for multiple permissions request is:

`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(acivityObj.this, new String[]{<list of permission>}, requestCode);`

Currently its working for you because your targetSdkVersion is 15.

Comment: But this works!!! Apk is installed from sdcard, not from google play, and I guess it has some hack

Comment: It won't grant any permission if you are running on OS >= 6.0. It just displays the information

Comment: You can easily verify in settings if the permissions are granted.

Comment: Yes, permissions enabled in app settings, but I didn't see any standard permission requests from this app.

Comment: What is your targetSdkVersion? And on which OS are your running the test?

Comment: It can only happen if targetSdkVersion < 23.

Comment: targetSdkVersion is 15 and I testing on Samsung S5, android 6.0.1

Comment: Permissions enabled in app settings, but I didn't see any standard permission requests from this app. How are dangerous permissions enabled?

Comment: The permission model will be implied if you increase your targetSdkVersion to 23. OS performs backward compatibility and grants the permission at install time if its lower than 23. But if user disables the permission in later stage, then you won't be able to request it. Since  your `targetSdkVersion` is 15, you are not seeing any permission dialogs

Comment: Beginning from August 2018 you won't be able to upload new app to Google play store if your `targetSdkVersion` is not atleast `26`

Answer (score 0):

If your Android project has **`targetSdkVersion < 23`** in `build.gradle` in app level module then it will not ask standard run time permission.
But it will run in your device which has the android version 6.0 because your **`compileSdkVersion > 23`** in `build.gradle` in app level module